# XSLT - what is the best way to process an element containing a delimited list using xsl:for-each?

Tags: xml, xslt, csv, foreach, transformation

I'm performing an XSLT transformation on some XML, with one of the elements looking like the following:

```
<element>Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4</element>
```

What's the best way to loop through each comma seperated value in this list using an `xsl:for-each`? I'd envision something like the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item at position 0, until item at last position">
     <!-- DO SOMETHING WITH ITEM -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 it's trivial

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(element, ',')">
  <!-- "." in here is the item from the comma separated list -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Regarding your comment:

> is it possible, that whilst looping through each value, to reference another value in the same list at say position 4? If I wanted to do something like "Item1 * Item4"?

For this I'd recommend storing the sequence that results from `tokenize` in a variable which you can later subscript into:

```
<!-- assuming the items in your list are actually numbers rather than "ItemN" -->
<xsl:variable name="items" as="xs:double*" select="tokenize(element, ',')" />
<xsl:for-each select="$items[position() lt 4]">
  <num><xsl:value-of select=". * $items[4]" /></num>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You may find it clearer to `for-each` over the indexes

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to 3">
  <!-- here "." or "current()" is the number 1, 2 or 3 -->
  <num><xsl:value-of select="$items[current()] * $items[4]" /></num>
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

If you're stuck with 1.0 then there's no concept of sequences of primitive values - you can only `for-each` over nodes - so the usual solution there is to use a tail recursive template

```
<xsl:template name="processCSV">
  <xsl:param name="value" />
  <xsl:if test="$value">
    <xsl:variable name="item" select="substring-before($value, ',')" />
    <!-- do stuff with $item here -->

    <xsl:call-template name="processCSV">
      <xsl:with-param name="value" select="substring-after($value, ',')" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

and call it with

```
<xsl:call-template name="processCSV">
  <xsl:with-param name="value" select="concat(element, ',')" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

(having the recursive template expect a trailing comma on the `$value` keeps the logic rather simpler).

Comment: Thanks @Ian, I'm actually using XSLT 2.0 so the first option has worked perfectly. Appreciate the update for 1.0, hopefully this will be useful to others.

Comment: @danw the only thing to watch out for is that because `.` is a string value rather than a node inside the `for-each`, if you need to refer to other nodes at relative paths then you need to preserve the outer context in a `<xsl:variable name="dot" select="."/>` before entering the `for-each`, so you can access `$dot/something` inside it.

Comment: I see, that will definitely come in useful, thank you! One other quick question, is it possible, that whilst looping through each value, to reference another value in the same list at say position 4? If I wanted to do something like "Item1 * Item4"?

Comment: @danw if you store the result of `tokenize` in a variable, yes.  See my edit for details.

Comment: Thank you @Ian, that's helped massively!